# How Rename confirm() buttons in ASP .NET MVC 5 View?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-5, jscript

I write in View inside the script tag function.When I click the menu item  in view call this function.

I want rename Java script confirm() buttons . How can I do this ? I don't know how write Java script code for this condition .

[image: Result Image]

I follow below code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
    var x;
    if (confirm("Press a button") == true) {
        x = "You pressed Cancel";
    } else {
        x = "You pressed OK";
    }
}
</script>
```

```html
<li><a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in" onclick="myFunction()"> </span> Exit</a></li>
```

Comment: You can't rename Javascript confirm buttons. In case you need personalized buttons, you have use third party model dialog with callbacks. Let me know if you need a jQuery example.

Comment: Please give me a jQuery example and explain me why I can't rename Java script confirm buttons . - @K D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ANSWER**

You can't control the appearance of confirm() or alert() Javascript dialogs, because they are native, consquently their design is based on the OS/browser.

What you can do:

- Own Dialog
- Extensions / Plugins
- Use a existing dialog js

**WAY TO BUILD OWN CLICK ELEMENTS**

```js
document.querySelector('#okLI').addEventListener('click', handleClick);
document.querySelector('#cancelLI').addEventListener('click', handleClick);

function handleClick(e){
  var target = e.target;
  var clickType = target.getAttribute("click-type");
  if(clickType > 0)
    console.log("CLICKED OK");
  if(clickType < 0)
    console.log("CLICKED CANCEL");
}

document.querySelector('#ok').addEventListener('click', clickButton);
document.querySelector('#cancel').addEventListener('click', clickButton);

function clickButton(e){
  var button = e.target;
  var buttonType = button.getAttribute("button-type");
  if(buttonType > 0)
    console.log("CLICKED OK");
  if(buttonType < 0)
    console.log("CLICKED CANCEL");
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="okLI" click-type="1">OK</li>
  <li id="cancelLI" click-type="-1">CANCEL</li>
</ul>
<button id="ok" button-type="1">OK</button>
<button id="cancel" button-type="-1">CANCEL</button>
```

You dont need to use buttons, you can add this to every element you want to click.

Comment: I don't need to use button , I use click to Exit item . I use inside list tag . Your code not help me .Please show me another example .  -@Dominik Noll

Comment: i added an example for li's.

Comment: I couldn't solve problem . I add my question image . I explain my problem : I want rename  Java script confirm() buttons Ok and Cancel . Let me know if you have any comments . Thank you -@Dominik Noll

Comment: Ah okey, you want to change the native confirm/alert buttons. You cannot control their appereace. You need to develop your own dialog or use some extension. Sorry

Comment: updated the answer. i am sorry for you, but its the only answer :-(

Comment: Thank you for explaining to me the problem - @Dominik Noll

Comment: maybe mark it as the answer, so everybody know, that you question got solved :-)

Answer (score 0):

As you requested, please check jQuery modal dialog for this feature.

you need to include following css and JS in your page.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">    
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Then add following script on your page.
Following script will configure a dialog for you with two buttons, "Delete" and "Cancel" and as you see both have a call back function where you can decide what to do on individual click.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $( function() {
    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height: "auto",
      width: 400,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Delete": function() {
         // YOUR LOGIC GOES HERE
          $( this ).dialog("close");
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $(this).dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
    });
  } );
  </script>
```

and then add following HTML on your page

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Delete Item?">
  <p>Do you want to proceed?</p>
</div>
```

Finally you just need to call following function, when you want to show dialog.
for example, to trigger it on a button click.. you can make it like following

```
<button type="button" id="btn_delete">Delete</button>

<script type="text/javascrpt">
$("#btn_delete").click(function(){
 $( "#dialog-confirm").dialog( "open" );
});
</script>
```

You can find more details on following link.

[jQuery Dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

**For javascript Confirm**
You cannot rename button titles for Javascript Confirm, as it is managed by browser and there is no any library or plugin which can manipulate these components.